# displaying charts from python executables in shell

Tags: python, charts, executable, dynamic-data-display

I'm using python 2.7 on Ubuntu to draw charts from text files containing data.

My point is, when using python executables in shell, I have no problem recording plots, but if I want them shown on my screen instead I have to go through the graphic interface. If possible, I would very much like to skip that part and get a dynamic display that I can interact with (as if I were to run my script from a python shell)!!

a MWE of what i'm doing is :

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('filename','r') as myfile: 
   DATA = np.genfromtxt(myfile,unpack=True)

   fig = plt.figure()
```

... my plot configuration ...

```
plt.savefig("image_name"+'.png')
plt.close()
```

**end of MWE**

Using this script image_name.png appears in my repertory. I tried replacing the last 2 lines with plt.plot() and plt.draw() but nothing happened.

Many thanks!
Michel

(edited)

Comment: Uhm. Display how, ASCII? You can't display graphics in a shell.

Comment: Try using ``plt.show()`` to display an interactive version of your plot.

Comment: Well I was hoping I could display the chart the same way it is displayed when running from spyder with plt.plot(), or at least skip the part where I go through the graphic interface using an alias : "alias = 'python_script xdg-open image_name.png' " but this doesn't work either :/